# What variable-IF tuner IC can I use for UHF applications?

Tags: rf, mixer

**What.** I'd like to build a multi-channel tuner that will pick up, say, two [known] channels, one at 156.3 MHz that's 50 kHz wide, and one at 855 MHz that's 25 kHz wide. Demodulation will be done in a Software-Defined Radio such as GNURadio.

**How** Rather than have one broadband tuner that picks up and downconverts this wide spectrum, I'd like to have two tuners - one that will pick up and downconvert the first channel to one low-IF, say 1MHz, and a second tuner that will pick up the second channel and downconvert it to another distinct low-IF (using a different LO of course), say 2MHz. Then I want to merely sum the two IFs, and then pass it through an ADC before feeding it to GNURadio where I have the channel selection and demodulation pieces. The advantage will be that the sampling rate can be kept much lower than if I used a wideband tuner to pick up everything in the 150-900 MHz range.

**Questions** (1) Do the RF experts see any problems with this idea? (2) The Elonics E4005 was a tuner chip that allowed user-selectable IF. Is there any similar variable-low-IF chip I could use since that chip is no longer available? (I'd use one such chip for each channel to be received).

**Alternative approach**. After reading up on some modern chips available it does appear that the chips available today are pretty much geared towards Zero-IF direct-conversion architectures and it would be simplest to build something with one of these. If I used one of these, then, would it be a valid approach to convert BOTH of the above channels to zero-IF, then UPconvert to two low-IFs, say 100kHz and 200kHz, and THEN sum the IFs before the ADC? That way much of the complexity is handled by the one chip, post which I only have to deal with low-frequency design and layout issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think that most of the Zero IF receiver IC's that are available have ADC's build in, so you actually have a digital output. Even without this, ZIF receivers have IQ baseband outputs, where you have 2 analog output's for a single receiver path, which would require a IQ modulator to upconvert this into a Lo-IF approach. It's my impression that "wideband" receivers that cover 150-900 MHz have multiple conversion stages, as well as IF filters, so that they would only work over a subset of that frequency range at one time, perhaps 2 to 10 MHz within that 150-900 MHz.

You might want to look at the Lime LM6002 transceiver part, which would give you a Digital I/Q output, which would possibly be easier to deal with in a signal processing point of view, as you have a single channel of digital information to deal with for each channel.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, no problem with this idea.
2. Usually, the only frequency restrictions built into a tuner chip are related to the range that the internal VCO(s) can cover. The exact input and output frequencies (and bandwidths) are generally determined by external components. I would think that you could use pretty much any modern chip, unless its datasheet specifically says that it has tighter constraints.

Comment: Thanks Dave. #1 is reassuring to know. On #2 it does seem that for most chips, varying the VCO to vary the IF can work within small ranges (+/- 10%), but not for, say, a range of IF from 0-5+ MHz, which is what I would need eventually if I accumulated not just 2 but 20-30 channels in the above manner which is my ultimate goal. One of the limitations appears to be in the fact that I would also need a narrow bandpass filter to isolate each channel and the VCO control per se does not provide that flexibility. Would I be right?